# WPF: get my object after ListView context menu right click instead of item index

Tags: wpf, listview, contextmenu

I have `ListView` contains my object:

```
public ObservableCollection<MyObject> objects { get; set; }
```

This is my `Context menu` right click event:

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myListView.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;
    int index = myListView.SelectedIndex;
}
```

So instead of take this `index` and find my `object` in my `collection` base on `index` number can i take the `object` at once ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to just fetch the object that has been selected

Have you tried using the .SelectedItem property of the list view?

```
private void MenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (myListView.SelectedIndex == -1)
        return;
    var obj = myListView.SelectedItem as MyObject;
}
```

Although I'm not sure why you can't just look up the object by its index in the collection. Both approaches would be valid, although the above approach has clearer intentions.